# %ifarch macro in spec file

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, specifications

What's the result of "%ifarch" macro in spec file. To build a package we have to pass "--target " (say i386) to rpmbuild as one parameter. If so, is the value of %ifarch will become i386. Otherwise %ifarch is the architecture of machine on which we are building the package OR is the architecture of machine on which we are installing the package?

Comment: Anybody is there to help me in this context?

Answer (score 3):

The %ifarch conditional is simply there to say 'if the architecture is equivalent to $MYARCH, run the following commands'. The context you've provided does not supply enough information to provide further details. You should review the conditionals documentation over at rpm.org.